# JavaScript Charts Vs Server Side Generated Images For SEO

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, javascript

I am currently using Google Visualization (Charts) API to display charts on my website. Fetch and Render on Search Console renders blank spaces in places of charts (quite understandably), while charts are showing fine for common users.

In case I switch to server side charts (PHP) I will be able to render charts as images to the browser. If I do so, will that help my search engine optimization efforts?

Comment: An image, without text, is never better than text.

Comment: What are you SEO goals?  Do you want your pages to rank well or do you want your charts to rank in image search?

Comment: @Rob I use charts as value addition to elaborate text content. Hence anyways there is plenty of text with or without charts

Comment: @Stephen I want my pages to rank well. Charts are additional components.

Answer (score 1):

There is no advantage in that since it won't help users. (Actually a chart is more useful and attractive. )

Please note that SEO is not about these small things.

And btw, the reason that the chart isn't rendered is because they have a robots.txt in the domain that API is coming from and it doesn't allow that piece of content to be rendered.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted the charts to be discoverable through Google Image search, it would make sense to link to the image versions from somewhere in your pages.

Unlike static images, Google Charts support interactivity and provide much richer user experience.

Regardless of how you display the charts, you should include the alt description and other metadata for accessibility and conventional SEO.